# Jquery show div form another page

Tags: jquery, load

I have this problem which i find a bit difficult to explain but I will try:

I have a page which fades in and out some `divs` taken from other pages with the `load()` function on click event. One of this `divs` contain a selection of pictures showed using `Jquery.Cycle`. Although on the page itself the `jquery.Cycle` works ok, when imported in to the page it does not. Hope my explanation is clear.

The code for importing is this:

```
$('#wrapper a').live("click", function(evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var oldDiv = $('#wrapper-content');
    var newDiv = $('#wrapper-content1').load(url + ' #wrapper-content');
    newDiv.hide();
    $('#wrapper-mid-in-right').prepend(newDiv);
    newDiv.fadeIn(1000);
    oldDiv.fadeOut(1000,function() {

    $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

As said the cycle effect works ok on the page. Please help me. F.

```
$('#gallery').cycle({
fx: 'scrollRight',
timeout: 100000,
speed: 500,
delay: -2000,
pager: '#pager'
```

});

Comment: you need to re-call the cycle init after the load is completed and it should work

Comment: Hi Toni. Thank you for your comment. Can you please tell me exactly how to re-call it? Sorry it isn't something I have done before.

Comment: i posted an answer, please let me know if I understood well

Comment: It works as before no Cycle plugin called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem has nothing to do with the code block you posted.  The plugin works in the page itself because of a few things:

1. the Cycle plugin is loaded
2. the markup already exists
3. the plugin is initiated appropriately (`$(document).ready()`, etc.)

When dynamically loading this content into a page, none of these facts may be true.

1. Is the Cycle plugin being loaded in this page?
2. You have to initiate the Cycle plugin after you've imported the new markup.

The JS in the the parent page (the page loading the Cycle content) should be something roughly like:

```
$('#wrapper-content1').load(url + ' #wrapper-content', function() {
    $('#gallery').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight',
        timeout: 100000,
        speed: 500,
        delay: -2000,
        pager: '#pager'
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes I understand that the problem is because the plugin is not "seeing" the new div loaded. But it is loaded on the page already. The question is how can I make the page "see" that the new div containing the Cycle is been loaded in thte page and react to it?

Comment: Like I demonstrated in the code block in my answer. The content of `my_cycle_stuff.foo` will be loaded into `#target`. Then, assuming that the new content has a `#my_slideshow` element, `cycle` will be applied to it.

Comment: The code is called by an external file. The one posted laready is the one tath calls the divs. I will post the cycle. The file is called in the main page.

Comment: Ayman I trying different things but I am getting a little confused :( Can you help?

Comment: There is no proper ajax. Div is imported with the load() function you can see in the code.

Comment: Got it. My bad... didn't see it. I've edited my answer, try that.

Comment: Do I have to add this in to hte main pag? doing so I need to re-call the url var. Or add it to the code I already have?

Comment: Ayman. Thank you. Your last suggestion worked! Really appreciated oyur help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing as below, I hope it will help you. I have written the comment about changes next to the code

```
function cycleFunction(){
 // implement cycle functionality here
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   cycleFunction(); // calling function for 1st time

   $('#wrapper a').on("click", function(evt) {    
    evt.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var oldDiv = $('#wrapper-content');
    var newDiv = $('<div>').attr('id','wrapper-content1'); // create the div with id
    $('#wrapper-mid-in-right').prepend(newDiv); include in the existing div
    $('#wrapper-content1').load(url + ' #wrapper-content', function(){
      cycleFunction(); // calling function everytime div load
    }); // load the new div
  });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you dku. Unfortunately it does not work. It fades in and fades out almost instantly. In nay case the main problemm is till there.

Comment: Thanks again but still not working. Divs are not imported and there aren't any errors in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$('#wrapper a').live("click", function(evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var oldDiv = $('#wrapper-content');
    var newDiv = $('#wrapper-content1').load(url + ' #wrapper-content');
    newDiv.hide();
    $('#wrapper-mid-in-right').prepend(newDiv);
    newDiv.fadeIn(1000);
    oldDiv.fadeOut(1000,function() {

    $(this).remove();
    });


    $('#gallery').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight',
        timeout: 100000,
        speed: 500,
        delay: -2000,
        pager: '#pager'

     });

});
```

Comment: Hi Toni. I made it work with Ayman suggestion (accepted answer). Thank you.